# Tag-It Jquery - But cant get watermark working

Tags: jquery, watermark, tag-it

I'm using Tag-it to generate

The problem I'm having is assigning a watermark on the input field. In Visual Studio I see the following:-

```
<ul id="mytags" class="tagclasspost">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->

            </ul>
```

In Firebug I see this:-

```
<div id="tagsimpletip" class="divpostsendtag">
<div>
<ul id="mytags" class="tagclasspost tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<li class="tagit-new">
<input class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: watermark on the input?.. what's that? did you mean "placeholder" text? (like "enter tags..." text which disappears when user clicks on input field)

Comment: and what the hell is visual studio? :D

Comment: Lol Sorry guys...I'm not a full on developer...just learning stuff as I go along! :)

ok - Yup your right Watermark on placeholder text. so when someone clicks on the input field the watermark disappears. Any idea's how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional placeholder text argument when calling the tagit on the input.

Example :

```
$(tags_selector).tagit({
        placeholderText: '**your placeholder**',
        afterTagAdded: function(event,tag){
           // Some processing
        },
        afterTagRemoved: function(event,tag){
           // Some processing
        }
    });
```

Refer this link :
[Placeholder text attribute](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/commit/a877af548684829a4adc1d449c88e755f4a0a2de)